# Change p:growl attribute "life" default value

Tags: jquery-ui, primefaces, jsf-2.2

world

I want to change for the the default value for p:growl "life" attribute for all pages without adding this attribute to  component.

**EDIT :**

```
<p:growl life="#{managedBean.time}" />
```

I want to apply (update) the same time for all growl component without adding the attribute for each one

Comment: Please edit your post and include what you have tried so far.

Comment: As you read, I put in my question a code that sets the value of the attribute from the ManagedBean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

I'd copy/paste [Growl.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.2.RC3/org/primefaces/component/growl/Growl.java) from package **org.primefaces.component.growl**  to my project at a created package with the same name. 
I'd modified the getLife() method (at line #93) as :

```
public int getLife() {
    return (java.lang.Integer) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.life, 10000);
}
```

I'd replace *6000* with **10000** (ms) equivalent to 10 seconds as new default value.

You can also define a context parameter in **web.xml** as :

```
<context-param>
  <description>The default life time for the growl primefaces component</description>
  <param-name>primefaces.GROWL_LIFE</param-name>
  <param-value>10000</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And the method will be implemented as :

```
public int getLife() {
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) 
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();            
        int life = Integer.parseInt(servletContext.getInitParameter("primefaces.GROWL_LIFE"));
        return (java.lang.Integer) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.life, life);
}
```